# Security considerations when using canvas in conjunction with file uploading

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, security

I'm working on a image editor/uploader based around [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/) where I grab image data out of an `<input>` tag, put it into a canvas, and after manipulating it, encode the data in base 64 and post it to my app with javascript, where it will be saved as a new image file. If it were a standard file upload, I would give the file a new (safe) name, test to make sure it was really an image file and copy it to strip any potentially malicious/personal EXIF data before making it available to users.

My question is - do those security measures make sense in the canvas situation, or are they pointless? Additionally, are there any security issues with my approach that I'm overlooking?

Fyi: the serverside decoding/etc will be done with php.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some of what you have asked (Not sure if all) are discussed by Shiflett [Here](http://shiflett.org/articles/file-uploads)
Check it and comment what you think of it!